# RecyclerView IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception, synchronized, android-recyclerview

Why exception execute when I removed some items in `RecyclerView` by using loop ?
I used `Collentions.synchronizedMap` in adapter and 'deleteItem method' use synchronized too (the method in fragment).

```
public void elementController(JsonObject jsonObject , String type)   {
    if ( jsonObject == null || type == null )    {
        return;
    }

    int position =0 , resultPosition =0;
    if ( type.equals("update") || type.equals("delete"))    {

        String id = jsonObject.get(ELEMENT_ID).getAsString();
        Map<String , Element> map = gridFragment.getMap();

        synchronized (map) {  
            for (String s : map.keySet()) {
                if (s.equals(id)) {
                    resultPosition = position;
                } else {
                    position++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(position-1 > gridFragment.getmAdapter().getData().size() || position <0)   {
        return;
    }
    switch (type)   {
        case "add":
            if (gridFragment.addElement(MyJsonParser.ElementParse(jsonObject),0)){
                LogUtils.logDebug(TAG,"add end");
            }
            break;
        case "update":
            if(gridFragment.updateElement( updateParser(jsonObject),resultPosition)){
                LogUtils.logDebug(TAG,"update end");
            }
            break;
        case "delete":
            if(gridFragment.deleteElement(jsonObject.get(ELEMENT_ID).getAsString(),resultPosition)){
                LogUtils.logDebug(TAG,"delete end");
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

---

```
public boolean deleteElement(final String id , final int position){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    synchronized (map) {
                        map.remove(id);
                        mAdapter.setData(map);
                        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();

    return true;
}
```

My error Log:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 0(offset:0).state:4
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3382)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:3340)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1810)
        at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:356)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1269)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:523)
        at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:151)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:1942)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.resumeRequestLayout(RecyclerView.java:1171)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:167)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:543)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5137)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:718)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

device not found

Comment: first code doesnt make sense, you do loop and only get one position from loop. no break condition

Comment: You're setting your mAdapter data after removing the item, and then attempting to remove the specified position, which in this case does not exist.

Comment: all of first code  called by service (i use socket network with server).
i got jsonarray from server and send jsonobjects to first code in jsonarray by for loop. so it is first loop.  i guess second jsonobject was sended by params to first code before ending first code.

Comment: I add all of my first method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Haven't read your code because I'm not familiar with the classes that you use but I know a fix to this problem. The problem occurs when the row element deleted is not the last one because of the index discrepancy between `dataList` index (your ArrayList to store data) and the parameter `final int position` in the method `onBindViewHolder`. Let me explain the issue in a graphical manner:

[image]

suppose we have a RecyclerView with three rows and we delete the 3rd row, at `dataList` index 2, (note that the deleted one is not the last element) after the removal, `dataList` index for the last element reduces 3 from 2 however, `final int position` still retrieves its position as 3 and that causes the problem. So, after removal, you can't use `final int position` as an index of element to be removed from `dataList`.

To fix this, introduce `int shift=0` and in a while loop, `try` removing the third item at (position-shift) and if it fails (in my case, it will) increment the shift and try removing it again until no exception occurs.

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    
    ...
    
        holder.removeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ //button used to remove rows
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (position == dataList.size() - 1) { // if last element is deleted, no need to shift
                            dataList.remove(position);
                            notifyItemRemoved(position);
                        } else { // if the element deleted is not the last one
                            int shift=1; // not zero, shift=0 is the case where position == dataList.size() - 1, which is already checked above
                            while (true) {
                                try {
                                    dataList.remove(position-shift);
                                    notifyItemRemoved(position);
                                    break;
                                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) { // if fails, increment the shift and try again
                                    shift++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
   ...
    }
```

Comment: works well for some time, until I get a loop of exceptions.

Answer (score 17):

For animation does not disappear, use:

```
holder.deleteItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                itemList.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position, itemList.size());
            }
        });
```

Comment: notifyItemRangeChanged(position, itemList.size());
this was helpful for me. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. IMO `notifyItemRemoved` should do this automatically, but oh well.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that happens because of concurrency access. I've encountered it. Easy to fix with `Iterator` or with a nice trick: you start to remove from the last item. However Z-A order with `Iterator` is better.

Recently I've improved and created a **FlexibleAdapter** which uses this solution.
Please, also have a look at the description and full working example: https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter

Answer (score 1):

it is works for me,like this:

```
fun removeData(position: Int) {
    this.notifyItemRemoved(position)
    this.notifyItemRangeChanged(position, imgList.size)
    this.imgList.removeAt(position)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, It's simpler than you think, just move `map.notifyItemRemoved(position)` from this

```
...
public void run() {
                    synchronized (map) {
                        map.remove(id);
                        mAdapter.setData(map);
                        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    }
                }
```

to this

```
public void run() {
                    synchronized (map) {
                        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                        map.remove(id);
                        mAdapter.setData(map);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

this only notifies the observers that are listening for layout changes.

Instead, try calling:

```
mAdpater.nofityDataChanged()
```

Comment: Don't call nofityDataChanged() unless you change the whole list content otherwise all animations are killed because Item is rebinded. Please have a look at my answer and at my FlexibleAdapter for all *notify()* methods